# Image max-height applied using JavaScript is sometimes not working for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The code below takes the height of my navigation bar which has a height that is not set, then takes the height of the viewport and sets the max-height of `.specific-image` to viewport height - navigation bar height. Sadly I realized I'm encountering a small problem.

When I load the page for the first time, the image max-height is set correctly in the `element.style` field after inspecting it, however, if I refresh using Ctrl+R, the image loses the max-height set by the JavaScript and starts using the max-height set in the CSS and I don't want that. If I then refresh again using Ctrl+Shift+R, the image gets its max-height set by JavaScript again.

Now considering that the code works correctly when I load an image for the first time and that Ctrl+Shift+R reloads the page without using the cache, I assume it has something to do with cached images only.

I've applied the code below but I don't think the problem can be seen here for some reason.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  function fitImage(){
 
    var navHeight = $("nav.navigation").outerHeight();
    var viewport = $(window).height();
    $(".specific-image").css({"max-height":viewport-navHeight});
  }
  
  $(".specific-image").on("load",fitImage);
  
  $(window).on("resize",fitImage);
  
});
```

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}
html {
    font-size: 16px;
}
body {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.navigation {
    background-color: #171717;
}
.navigation-ul {
    display: flex;
}
.navigation-ul>li:not(.dropdown) {
    padding: 15px 13px 15px 13px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: #151719;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.specific-image-flexbox {
    display: flex;
}
.specific-image-column {
    flex: 4;
}
.specific-image-container {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.specific-image {
    display: block;
    max-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class='navigation'>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="navigation-ul">
      <li><a href="">Images</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Albums</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="specific-image-flexbox">
  <div class="specific-image-column">
    <div class='specific-image-container'>
      <img class='specific-image' src='https://odysseyonline-img.rbl.ms/simage/https%3A%2F%2Faz616578.vo.msecnd.net%2Ffiles%2F2016%2F07%2F18%2F636044656439844367681973023_453768-cats-cute.jpg/2000%2C2000/UWdtxOCqm5JAgBMr/img.jpg' alt='Random image' />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: run it on window load - height and width are not supplied properly until the image has loaded (they can sometimes load after the dom is ready - therefore jquery will know about the image, but not have the correct dimensions).  Also binding it to the load event of the image will sometimes not work as I have found the load event for images sometimes doesn't fire if loaded from the cache (which is why you are having to do the hard refresh for it to work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
$(".specific-image").on("load",fitImage);
```

[From jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/):

> Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load() shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with this that should be noted. These are:
>
> It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
>   It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
>   It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
>   Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

Hence, I suggest to replace that line with:

```
fitImage(); // a direct call on doc ready....
```

```js
function fitImage(){

    var navHeight = $("nav.navigation").outerHeight();
    var viewport = $(window).height();
    $(".specific-image").css({"max-height":viewport-navHeight});
}
$(document).ready(function(){

    fitImage();

    $(window).on("resize",fitImage);

});
```

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}
html {
    font-size: 16px;
}
body {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.navigation {
    background-color: #171717;
}
.navigation-ul {
    display: flex;
}
.navigation-ul>li:not(.dropdown) {
    padding: 15px 13px 15px 13px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: #151719;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.specific-image-flexbox {
    display: flex;
}
.specific-image-column {
    flex: 4;
}
.specific-image-container {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.specific-image {
    display: block;
    max-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class='navigation'>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul class="navigation-ul">
            <li><a href="">Images</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Albums</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="specific-image-flexbox">
    <div class="specific-image-column">
        <div class='specific-image-container'>
            <img class='specific-image' src='https://odysseyonline-img.rbl.ms/simage/https%3A%2F%2Faz616578.vo.msecnd.net%2Ffiles%2F2016%2F07%2F18%2F636044656439844367681973023_453768-cats-cute.jpg/2000%2C2000/UWdtxOCqm5JAgBMr/img.jpg' alt='Random image' />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That fixed my issue flawlessly. Thank you!